# Wordpress custom hook to an another plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am making a custon plugin, where I want to have a function, but i want to fire it from a different plugin.

Just to be safe, I do not want to modify the original plugin.

The parent plugin uses:

```
add_filter( 'gform_replace_merge_tags', 'gf_simple_replace_response_code', 10, 7 );
function gf_simple_replace_response_code( $text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {  

$custom_merge_tag = '{response_code}';

if ( strpos( $text, $custom_merge_tag ) === false ) {
    return $text;
}    

$response_code = gform_get_meta( $entry['id'], 'response_code' );
$text = str_replace( $custom_merge_tag, $response_code, $text );

return $text;
}
```

My code will be the following:

```
add_action('gform_replace_merge_tags_action', 'call_api', 10, 7);
function call_api($response_text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format){}
```

Will it work if I add this line to the original plugin, before it returns the text?:

```
do_action( 'gform_replace_merge_tags_action', $response_text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format);
```

Do I have to reference the scripts somehow?
Can I manage this without modifying the original plugin?
Im new to PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: you have 2 contrary questions there: yes adding code to the original plugin should work - why didn't you just try it? rather than expecting others to check it for you?  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: To avoid modifying the original plugin, you could use the same filter that the plugin is using, but add your filter with a LATER priority (risky)  and then actually do your update code.  Not ideal as filters are meant to 'filter' data not trigger actions.  You may get odd behaviour.

Comment: I did not try it, because its a payment addon, and I was afraid i do something worng. I asked it here, just to be safe. I will give it a try.

Comment: Zoltan, every payment service should have a test mode or 'sandpit' for development.  You should not be testing on a live system.